# Create Worksheet from Master sheet and hyperlink them in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

1. I have a master worksheet listing all data in rows.
2. A template to add more details for each unique record
3. Need to create a worksheet for each entry in column "C" and updating the template with details in Name ( D) & Contact ( E) columns of respective row.
4. Then Hyperlink the respective sheet with the entry in the rows.

With the help of few posts here i was able to run below code, which creates sheets, but i need help of populating data in Template from Master sheet and also creating a Hyperlink

```
Option Explicit
Sub SheetsFromTemplate()
Dim wsMASTER As Worksheet, wsTEMP As Worksheet, wasVISIBLE As Boolean
Dim shNAMES As Range, Nm As Range

With ThisWorkbook                
    Set wsTEMP = .Sheets("Template")
    wasVISIBLE = (wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetVisible) 
    If Not wasVISIBLE Then wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetVisible 
    
    Set wsMASTER = .Sheets("Master")

    Set shNAMES = wsMASTER.Range("C4:C" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlConstants) 
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Nm In shNAMES
        If Not Evaluate("ISREF('" & CStr(Nm.Text) & "'!A1)") Then
           wsTEMP.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
           ActiveSheet.Name = CStr(Nm.Text)
        End If
    Next Nm
    
    wsMASTER.Activate 
    If Not wasVISIBLE Then wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

     MsgBox "All sheets created"
End Sub
```

Master sheet which is updated often
[image]

Sample worksheet
[image]

Template
[image]

Comment: Thanks braX, Just added additional comments and help needed

Comment: I would say loop through the sheets checking the name against Column D in your master (using either `.Find` or `Application.Match`) and if it matches one, then do a `.value = .value` between the master and looped sheet with the relevant cells (Or do another loop through the relevant cells if you want your script a bit cleaner).

Comment: Thank you Simon, I am not so good at VBA, still a noob. Could you help me put the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub SheetsFromTemplate()
    
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet, wasVisible As Boolean
    Dim shNames As Range, Nm As Range, wsEntry As Worksheet, entryName
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsTemp = .Sheets("Template")
        wasVisible = (wsTemp.Visible = xlSheetVisible)
        If Not wasVisible Then wsTemp.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        
        Set wsMaster = .Sheets("Master")
    
        Set shNames = wsMaster.Range("C4:C" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlConstants)
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each Nm In shNames
            entryName = Nm.Text
            Set wsEntry = Nothing 'EDIT
            On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no sheet with this name
            Set wsEntry = .Sheets(entryName)
            On Error GoTo 0 'stop ignoring errors
            If wsEntry Is Nothing Then
               wsTemp.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
               Set wsEntry = .Sheets(.Sheets.Count) 'get the copy
               wsEntry.Name = CStr(Nm.Text)
            End If
            With wsEntry
                'transfer/update values from Master sheet
                .Range("B2").Value = entryName
                .Range("B3").Value = Nm.Offset(0, 1)
                '...etc
                wsMaster.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Nm, Address:="", _
                    SubAddress:=wsEntry.Range("A1").Address(, , , True), _
                    TextToDisplay:=Nm.Text
            End With
        Next Nm
        
        wsMaster.Activate
        If Not wasVisible Then wsTemp.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    MsgBox "All sheets created"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, but this creates the first record and stops, its not looping.

Comment: Where does it stop?  Have you checked the range `shNames` and what it refers to?

Comment: It stops at first record, but creates hyperlink for all entries in Row and links to first record. shNames range is C4:C ( till the last entry)

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Tim Williams  , works flawlessly. Learnt a lot too.